# Reading a text file line by line and storing an object in the array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The code I've currently created stores the first line of the text file, creates a new Vehicle object and puts it in the array at the first position of null, and stores the same line in every null value in the array. I need it to be able to:

Store the contents of the first line, then store a new Vehicle object in the first place in the array that is null. Then repeat until there are no more lines.

I believe it is a problem with my for loop.
Note - I am required to use Array instead of ArrayList

```
public void addVehicle(Vehicle[] Honda) throws FileNotFoundException
{

        if(canAddVehicle() == true)
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++)
        {
            if(vehicles[i] == null)
            {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

                Honda[i] = new Vehicle();
                Honda[i].readRecord(reader);
                vehicles[i] = Honda[i];

                reader.close();
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Vehicle Added!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You can not add more than 4 vehicles.");
        }
}
```

Vehicle class:

```
public void readRecord(Scanner reader)
{

    setMake(reader.next());
    setModel(reader.next());
    setYear(reader.nextInt());
    setvin(reader.next());
    setValue(reader.nextDouble());
    setMilesDriven(reader.nextInt());
    setLastOilChange(reader.nextInt());



}
```

Data file:

```
Hyundai Sonata  2010    ABC236347NM2N2NW2   18455.34    8765    7567
Chevy   Blazer  1998    1234H32343LMN3423   29556.65    38559   38559
```

//EDIT\
**Constraits**: I cannot create any new public methods or constructors, and I cannot have any additional class level data

Comment: You should stick to this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410050/reading-a-file-line-by-line-while-storing-an-object-in-an-array-for-each-line

Comment: sorry, i've been up for 9 straight hours now trying to finish this and it's really difficult to even think anymore. i just need to get this done

Comment: You have to post the content of data file so we can suggest.

Comment: @MJ93- Take a look at Jon's post (an elegant solution). However, in your code-snippet, you have to move  **Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);** before the loop and **reader.close();*** after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution!

```
public boolean addVehicle(Vehicle[] Honda) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    boolean found = false;
    int position = 0;
        if(canAddVehicle() == true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length && !found; i++)
            {
                if(vehicles[i] == null)
                {
                    position = i;
                    found = true;
                }
            }

               Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
               while(reader.hasNext())
               {
                   Honda[position] = new Vehicle();
                   Honda[position].readRecord(reader);
                   vehicles[position] = Honda[position];
                   position++;

               }
                reader.close();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looping *within* the `readRecord` method, even though that's meant to only store one object, isn't it?

It's possible that you can just remove the `while` loop - although that then relies on the `addVehicle` caller knowing how many entries are in the file.

It seems more likely that you should have a method to read everything from a file, populating a `List<Vehicle>` and returning it. For example:

```
public List<Vehicle> readVehicles(String file)
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

    List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    try
    {
        while (reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            vehicles.add(Vehicle.readFromScanner(reader));
        } 
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.close();
    }
    return vehicles;
}

// In vehicle
public static Vehicle readFromScanner(Scanner scanner)
{
    String make = reader.next();
    String model = reader.next();
    int year = reader.nextInt();
    String vin = reader.next();
    // Don't use double for currency values
    BigDecimal value = reader.nextBigDecimal();
    int milesDriven = reader.nextInt();
    // Shouldn't this be some sort of date type?
    int lastOilChange = reader.nextInt();

    // I'll assume you have a constructor like this
    return new Vehicle(make, model, year, vin, value, milesDriven,
                       lastOilChange);
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes I don't know why I had the while loop there, I'm sorry it's so late and I've been working on this for 9 straight hours trying to get it finished. I haven't learned about ListArrays yet so I'm not sure how to do that at all

Comment: @MJ93: See my edit - but to be honest you may well be best talking to your teacher if you've been given an assignment which would work so much better using concepts you haven't encountered yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info on ArrayLists, I guess I should have explained first: Some of the code was already provided for me, the methods that I create must be private (helper) methods. So I will not be able to create a new public method inside the Vehicle class. It's a requirement

Comment: @MJ93: It's very hard to answer a question when there are constraints we haven't been told about. The structure of the original code is a little odd to say the least. We may be able to help more if you give us more information.

Comment: What I'm restricted to: I cannot add any new public methods or constructors, and I cannot declare any additional Class level data

Comment: @MJ93: So make the methods I've given package access instead of public. But do you *have* to implement the somewhat odd method you've declared in your original post? (The `addVehicle` one.) It seems fundamentally odd given the signature and its behaviour.

Comment: No I do not have to add that, I originally had the code so that only 1 line would be read at any given time so it worked out. But thank you, I will try that